# How can I build a list of days, months, years from a calendar object in Java?

Tags: java, forms, date, calendar

I want to build a date widget for a form, which has a select list of months, days, years. since the list is different based on the month and year, i cant hard code it to 31 days. (e.g february has 28 days not 30 or 31 and some years even 29 days)
How can I use the calendar or [joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) object to build me these lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *strongly* recommend that you avoid the built-in date and time APIs in Java.

Instead, use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). This library is similar to the one which will (hopefully!) make it into Java 7, and is much more pleasant to use than the built-in API.

Now, is the basic problem that you want to know the number of days in a particular month?

EDIT: Here's the code (with a sample):

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.chrono.*;

public class Test   
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        System.out.println(getDaysInMonth(2009, 2));
    }

    public static int getDaysInMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        // If you want to use a different calendar system (e.g. Coptic)
        // this is the code to change.
        Chronology chrono = ISOChronology.getInstance();
        DateTimeField dayField = chrono.dayOfMonth();        
        LocalDate monthDate = new LocalDate(year, month, 1);
        return dayField.getMaximumValue(monthDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that relevant? I.e. will that help him build a date widget?

Comment: @mmyers: Absolutely. Once we've fully identified what he's trying to do, if he does it all with Joda Time it will end up being a lot simpler, I believe.

Comment: @Jon. Very good comment indeed. Not so sure about this as an "answer"

Comment: It'll turn into a proper answer when I've found out the way to get the relevant information from Joda Time. I'm positive it's in here somewhere :)

Comment: joda-time, the standard answer of all Java date/time questions. In fact, Jon, you could add a simple if(currentQ.tags.contains("java") && currentQ.tags.contains("calendar")) { addWikiAnswer("Use joda-time"); lockQuestion(currentQ); } to SO's code...

Comment: @Esko: Yup. It should certainly be part of the answer to all questions asking for help using the built-in API, unless it specifically states why Joda Time is not an option. The more work I do with date/time data, the scarier the whole topic becomes - and the more thankful I become for Joda Time.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
int lengthOfMonth = 
    YearMonth.from( 
                      LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) 
                  )
             .lengthOfMonth() ;
```

## java.time

The [Answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/668113/642706) is correct but now outdated. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

### `LocalDate`

The code in java.time is similar to that of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), with a `LocalDate` class. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( “America/Montreal” );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

You may interrogate for each part, year number, month, etc. Note that months are number sanely, 1-12 for January-December (unlike in the legacy classes).

```
int year = today.getYear();
int monthNumber = today.getMonthValue(); // 1-12 for January-December.
int dayOfMonth = today.getDayOfMonth();
```

You can assemble a `LocalDate` object from those parts.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( year , monthNumber , dayOfMonth );
```

### `YearMonth`

To ask for the [length of the month](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#lengthOfMonth--), use the [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld );
int lengthOfMonth = ym.lengthOfMonth();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) object will tell you the number of days in the current month using `getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`.  See an example [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/GetDaysInMonth.html).

From that you can update your lists on each change.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of date picker implementations out there for java, which can be used via swing or a web ui. I would attempt to reuse one of these and avoid writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a list of months:

```
String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
    List<String> allMonths = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String singleMonth: months){
        allMonths.add(singleMonth);
    }
    System.out.println(allMonths);
```